# Prove that X has a chi square distribution

Tags: probability

If $X_1,\dots ,X_{30}\sim N(1,\sigma^2)$ and 
$\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{\sum(X_i-1)^2}{30}, $
then show that  $30\,\hat σ^2 /σ^2$ has a chi-square distribution with $30$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem posted by someone who doesn't know its prerequisites. Specifically, what is the distribution of $\dfrac{X_i - 1} \sigma\vphantom{\dfrac\int\int}$ and consequently what is the distribution of $\dfrac{{}\,\sqrt{30}\,{}}\sigma\cdot \dfrac{X_i-1}{\sqrt{30}}\vphantom{\dfrac\int\int}$? You're adding up a sum of squares of random variables with a certain distribution. You should know something about that before attempting this problem. And as stated, the conclusion is WRONG; it can be proved only if you assume independence, which you haven't mentioned.${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think you should have asked for help understanding the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$30\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{30}\left(\frac{X_i-1}{\sigma}\right)^2$$

Then, the $X_i$ are independent and $\frac{X_i-1}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

So $30\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}$ has the same distribution as $Y_1^2+\dots+Y_{30}^2$ where the $Y_i$ are independent and $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Thus, it's a $\chi^2$ with $30$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Independence is not mentioned in the problem as now stated. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I know. I guess OP just forgot to mention it...

Comment: I thought it was assumed? It would more difficult if it wasn't independent.

Comment: @risdel : There is a certain context in which something similar to a presumption of independence holds, but as long as a problem is only mathematics one is not in that context.  Often people forget to mention that hypothesis, and in my view they ought to mention it explicitly.  (By "only" I don't be "merely"; rather I mean excluding all else.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I see, will make sure to include assumptions in future questions. Thank you.